# iOS: Debugging Release/Distribution PUSH Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

### I know I have done this successfully in the past.

I have an app with different dev streams. The app is currently in the App Store, and I am trying to track down an issue related to PUSH notifications that seems to be plaguing that version only. So, I am trying to debug Production/Release PUSH notifications. I know I have done this in the past, but it has been a while, and I have forgotten the exact set of settings that allowed this to work.

App setup is as follows:

- App is tied in to Azure Notification Hub.
- Notification Hub has a Production APNS certificate.
- Currently, PUSH notifications succeed when the app is deployed to a device either by:

  - Downloading from the App Store, or
  - Building in Release mode with a Distribution Provisioning Profile

The problem is with a particular **KIND** of PUSH notification, and specifically how the app responds to it (so, it's not the PUSH notification that is the problem, but I need to be able to debug incoming PUSH notifications).

I **think** I remember the following to enable debugging Distribution PUSH notifications:

- You have to build in Release mode.
- You have to build with a Development Provisioning Profile.

But something is going wrong. No matter what combination of settings I choose, I am either unable to debug my app (and then the PUSH notifications works), or I am able to debug my app (and then the PUSH notifications fail). Has something changed in Xcode, or am I making some other mistake? Like I said before, I am **positive** that I have been able to get this working in the past. How can I get it working now?

Comment: I've also noticed similar problems with debugging the APNS via the azure hub. For some reason, device tokens and registrations in debugging states for iOS seem to be really flakey at the moment.